# Unable to run codacy maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, codacy

I am trying to run codacy check on my project and see error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gavinmogan:codacy-maven-plugin:1.1.0:coverage (default-cli) on project account-core: Report file does not exist -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.gavinmogan:codacy-maven-plugin:1.1.0:coverage (default-cli) on project action-cmm-virtual-account-core: Report file does not exist
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Report file does not exist
    at com.gavinmogan.CodacyCoverageReporterMojo.execute(CodacyCoverageReporterMojo.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
```

What is that "Report file does not exist" its talking about ?

Though Codacy is running my pom configuration has only below plugin :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${pmd-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                    <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                    <skipEmptyReport>false</skipEmptyReport>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>../ruleset/ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
                        <version>${pmd.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pmd-xml</artifactId>
                        <version>${pmd.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pmd-vm</artifactId>
                        <version>${pmd.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Internally codacy uses pmd is what i heard. Apart from this there is nothing else related to bugfinding in pom.

Comment: post your configuration from POM.

Comment: do you have jacoco configured? where is the jacoco file on your project dir?